# Passing value from DB to API

Tags: javascript, php

What I want to do here is when I add a new user the `$steamids` would get that new value. But the problem is that I'm not getting info at all. It seems that it doesn't get the propery `steam_id` from database. What can I do here ?

```
<?php    
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgo', 'root', '');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $users = $dbh->query($sql);

    foreach($users as $r) {        
        $steamids = $r['steam_id'];        
        $APIKEY = '*******************';
        $steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
        $json_object = file_get_contents($steamAPI);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $json_object;
    }
```

When I add just plain ID to the `$steamids` than it's working fine. But obviously then I can display only one user. I want to display more than one and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

**OK!** **EDIT**

So I did this:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgo', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT steam_id FROM users");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchColumn();

$steamids = $result;

$APIKEY = '*******';

$steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
$json_object= file_get_contents($steamAPI);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_object;
```

And now I'm getting the steam_id but only of first row, how should I get everyones ID's ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this?

```
<?php 

error_reporting(-1); // Example where to add the PHP error reporting
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // if error reporting is switched off

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgo', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `steam_id` FROM `users`");

$APIKEY = '*******************';
$steamids = array();
if ($sth->execute()) {
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $steamids [] = $row["steam_id"];

        $steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=". $row["steam_id"] ."&key=". $APIKEY ."&format=json";
        $json_object = file_get_contents($steamAPI);

        echo $json_object;

        sleep(1); // To pause the script for 1 second, OR try "usleep(500000);" for 0.5 second sleep, yes, "usleep".
    }
}

echo "Test";
```

Comment: Not even an error or anything like that? Hmmm. Try echo'ing something just after the if statement closing } bracket and see if that is being echoed, if it's not, then you have PHP errors turned off. Which you can turn on for this session by adding this to the start of your PHP file "error_reporting(-1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);"

Edited my answer to include what I want you to try test

Comment: If theres more than one row let's say 2 rows than I get nothing. If it's only one row in DB then I get the info.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting, do you know if steam API has some kind of time out so that you can't make too many consecutive requests in a short period of time?

Comment: After some digging around, looks like steam api does have some sort of throttle in place to prevent too many consecutive calls. Besides that, I don't see what could be wrong with your code now

Comment: I think I need somehow to fetch all the JSON object. Because if I go to `info.php` where this code located I get only one JSON object with the latest `steamid`

Comment: Hmm try adding a 1 second pause between queries, I know it's not ideal, but see if it works. I edited the code to show you how to pause for 1 second. If it works for one second, try bring it down to 0.5seconds by using usleep(500000); and then keep going down till you find a number that works 100% of the time.

What this does is makes the PHP script pause for the given time before it runs the next request with the next Steam ID

Comment: I tell you to try this out because I looked at the Steam API wiki page, no where does it mention how to call multiple profile information in the one JSON call unfortunately :(, so I guess that is something they just don't let third-party applications do

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot (Looping through using fetch)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgo', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT steam_id FROM users");
$sth->execute();
while($result = $sth->fetch())
{
    $steamids = $result['steam_id'];
    $APIKEY = '*******';
    $steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
    $json_object= file_get_contents($steamAPI);
    echo $json_object;
}
```

Comment: If theres more than one row let's say 2 rows than I get nothing. If it's only one row in DB then I get the info.